# Run .bat for particular user

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, authentication, logoff

I've an Excel File say Log.xls which tracks his login & logout time. I want to open this when a particular user Logs In as well as when he logs out.

I found a solution for this,

1. Write a .bat file say OpenLog.bat which opens Log.xls

   ```
   @ECHO OFF 
   @ECHO "Please Wait, Your log file is about to open... Please Fill Your Work Log..."
   @CD E:\Anoop\Documents
   @CALL Log.xls
   @ECHO "Have a nice time"
   ```
2. Run gpedit.msc

   Under User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Open Scripts

   Add Bat File Name to it.

I want this Log.xls to run for a particular user account on my windows XP machine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So let's assume the username is "John"

```
@ECHO OFF
if '%username%' == 'John' goto label1 else exit
label1:
ECHO "Please Wait, Your log file is about to open... Please Fill Your Work Log..."
CD E:\Anoop\Documents
CALL Log.xls
ECHO "Have a nice time"
```

Comment: Check your answer! There is an error. '%username%0=='Steve' will also open the log.

Comment: Your code after `label1:` is always executed. change the `if` to something like `if not '%username%' == 'John' exit /b` and remove the `label1:`

Comment: This happen because the "goto label1" must be enclosed in parentheses: `if '%username%' == 'John' (goto label1) else exit`, but this is not a good way to do it... You may use Frank's suggestion...